# html5: Significance of attribute named required in checkbox/radio

Tags: html, attributes, specifications

On form submission, how could you possibly mark a checkbox/radiobutton as required?

Source of inspiration: [Pekka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901410/correct-way-to-do-html5-checkbox/4901438#4901438) to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901410/correct-way-to-do-html5-checkbox/4901438)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Required checkboxes are not unusual. Practically every registration form uses some form of the "I have read and accept the User Agreement" checkbox.

If you have Opera handy try out the code below. The form won't submit unless the checkbox is checked.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>html5</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>html5 test</h1>
  <form action="/">
    <input type="checkbox" required="required" id="cb" name="cb">
    <label for="cb">required checkbox</label>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't need `required="required"`, just adding `required` is enough.

Comment: `required="required"` is valid XHTML though. An attribute must have a value.

Comment: XHTML is not a requirement of HTML5

Comment: naveen, bro you missed this because even experienced programmers tend to forget or overlook some common things while working and having bigger issues like application flows and the like. :)

Every programmer faces logical mistakes.

naveen, i thank you, your question helped myself. i was working on a project. did R & D found about required attribute and now i remember it.

well everyone including the comments from Emily, Ben, @leggetter and Neil shared helpful information.

thanks all.

Comment: But you do have to close your `<form>` :)

Answer (score 7):

For checkboxes, the best way is probably to pre-select it and set it to disabled. Just kidding.

To ensure one radio button in a group has been selected, either start with a default choice or validate using javascript. There are no HTML-ways to do that because every possible selection is valid.

In html5 there is a [required](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.checkbox.html#input.checkbox.attrs.required) attribute for checkboxes.

They are somehow weird, so let me quote something to explain how they work.

For checkboxes, the required attribute shall only be satisfied when one or more of the checkboxes with that name in that form are checked.

For radio buttons, the required attribute shall only be satisfied when exactly one of the radio buttons in that radio group is checked.

Of course you always have to validate server side because the client can always send you whatever he desires. Just use these methods for better user experience.

Comment: +1 for guesses. highly unlikely unless you present a stronger argument :)

Comment: what guesses? just updated the answer according to html5 sepcs

Comment: +1 the specs are clear, but this is still *weird*. Doesn't make any sense from a UI point of view.

Comment: The problem with @Joe Hopfgartner's quote is that it comes from a currently unauthoritative source: whatwg.org/specs/web-forms/current-work That's the old Web Forms 2 work; the top of the doc admits that it's been superseded by HTML5. Don't base your expectations on that document!

Comment: Although what you say about radio buttons is right (`required` on any one of the radio buttons means that exactly one of all the radio buttons with the same name must be checked), it looks like only the checkboxes with the `required` attribute have to be checked, not all the checkboxes with the same name. As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yXBHU/1/), only the first 2 checkboxes have to be checked, not the third one. At least in Chrome!

Answer (score 7):

I tested *required* attribute for Radio Buttons today on Firefox 17.0.1 on XP SP2.

It seems to comply with the specification of *required* attribute for radio buttons/groups. As Firefox prompts "Please select one of these options." for both of the code snippets below:

Either you set *required* attribute for each of the radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required="required" />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" required="required" />
```

Or Any One of the Radio elements

```
<input type="radio" name="color" value="blue" />
<input type="radio" name="color" value="red" required="required" />
<input type="radio" name="color" value="green" />
```

Any comments and updates are welcome.

Comment: Link to specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.radio.html#input.radio.attrs.required

Can anyone find a reference indicating which of these two styles is preferred for marking a radio button group as required? I can't find that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it on a radio button in Firefox 4. Adding `required` to one radio input, then submitting before selecting one, triggers a "Please select one of these options" tooltip.

E.g. this works:

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" required />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" />
```

Comment: Chrome 12 does the same.  Safari 5 and IE 9 don't.  Tested on Win7.