# Required attribute on multiple checkboxes with the same name?

Tags: forms, html

I have a list of checkboxes **with the same name** attribute, and I need to validate that at least one of them has been selected.

But when I use the html5 attribute "required" on all of them, the browser (chrome & ff) doesn't allow me to submit the form unless all of them are checked.

sample code:

```
<label for="a-0">a-0</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="q-8" id="a-0" required />
<label for="a-1">a-1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="q-8" id="a-1" required />
<label for="a-2">a-2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="q-8" id="a-2" required />
```

When using the same with radio inputs, the form works as expected (if one of the options is selected the form validates)

According to [Joe Hopfgartner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901576/html5-significance-of-attribute-named-required-in-checkbox-radio) (who claims to quote the html5 specs), the supposed behaviour is:

> For checkboxes, the required attribute shall only be satisfied when one or more of the checkboxes with that name in that form are checked.
>
> For radio buttons, the required attribute shall only be satisfied when exactly one of the radio buttons in that radio group is checked.

am i doing something wrong, or is this a browser bug (on both chrome & ff) ??

Comment: Probably more straightforward (and backwards compatible) to use javascript & jQuery to validate your checkboxes.

Comment: The problem with @Joe Hopfgartner's quote is that it comes from a currently unauthoritative source: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-forms/current-work/  That's the old Web Forms 2 work; the top of the doc admits that it's been superseded by HTML5.  Don't base your expectations on that document!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sorry, now I've read what you expected better, so I'm updating the answer.

Based on the [HTML5 Specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.checkbox.html) from W3C, nothing is wrong. I created [this JSFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/kXsj9/6/) and it's behaving correctly based on the specs (for those browsers based on the specs, like Chrome 11 and Firefox 4):

```html
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="q" id="a-0" required autofocus>
    <label for="a-0">a-1</label>
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="q" id="a-1" required>
    <label for="a-1">a-2</label>
    <br>

    <input type="checkbox" name="q" id="a-2" required>
    <label for="a-2">a-3</label>
    <br>

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I agree that it isn't very usable (in fact many people have complained about it in the [W3C's mailing lists](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-wg-issue-tracking/2010Apr/0008.html)).

But browsers are just following the standard's recommendations, which is correct. The standard is a little misleading, but we can't do anything about it in practice. **You can always use JavaScript for form validation, though**, like some great jQuery validation plugin.

Another approach would be choosing a [polyfill](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills) that can make (almost) all browsers interpret form validation rightly.

Comment: Erick, exactly what statements in HTML5 make you think that the required attribute governs each individual checkbox even when they are in a group (i.e., have the same name)?  I can't find that it specifies clearly one way or the other.

Comment: Chrome 26 and Firefox 20 are asking for all checkboxes to be checked on the linked jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/kXsj9/6/

Comment: @John-Philip, sure! Exactly like I said in my answer and like the [specs](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.checkbox.html#input.checkbox.attrs.required) says "that **the element** is a required part of form submission", the `required` attribute works for each element but not for groups of elements. Not a very usable thing, but is the way it's meant to be in the specs.

Answer (score 32):

You can make it with jQuery a less lines:

```
$(function(){

    var requiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');

    requiredCheckboxes.change(function(){

        if(requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
            requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
        }

        else {
            requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
        }
    });

});
```

With ***$(':checkbox[required]')*** you select all checkboxes with the attribute *required*, then, with the *.change* method applied to this group of checkboxes, you can execute the *function* you want when any item of this group changes. In this case, if any of the checkboxes is checked, I remove the *required* attribute for all of the checkboxes that are part of the selected group.

I hope this helps.

Farewell.

Comment: Awesome!  I think it's good to add .trigger('change') next to .change(...) bind to ensure rule works if no input clicked.

Comment: It fails if there is no change! I've already ticked one checkbox and saved, when I try to save again, it ask me to tick another checkbox of same group!

We should not use onChange! All the answers with on Change having this bug.https://imgur.com/a/jAKdv7z

Comment: @SaurabhDhar you have to call `requiredCheckboxes.trigger('change');` if you have a default `checked` checkbox. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 10):

To provide another approach similar to the answer by @IvanCollantes.
It works by additionally filtering the required checkboxes by name. I also simplified the code a bit and checks for a default `checked` checkbox.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var requiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');
  requiredCheckboxes.on('change', function(e) {
    var checkboxGroup = requiredCheckboxes.filter('[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]');
    var isChecked = checkboxGroup.is(':checked');
    checkboxGroup.prop('required', !isChecked);
  });
  requiredCheckboxes.trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form target="_blank">
  <p>
    At least one checkbox from each group is required...
  </p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Checkboxes Group test</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1" checked="checked" required="required">test-1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="2" required="required">test-2
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="3" required="required">test-3
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Checkboxes Group test2</legend>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="test2[]" value="1" required="required">test2-1
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="test2[]" value="2" required="required">test2-2
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="test2[]" value="3" required="required">test2-3
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <hr>
  <button type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to override the default message in popup with our own message?

Comment: @VivekSancheti see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272433/html5-form-required-attribute-set-custom-validation-message

Comment: Thats not working. http://stackoverflow.com/q/38069634/5278270 I tried it and have posted this question.

Comment: How can I change the message from "Please check this box if you want to proceed" to a custom message?

Comment: Use `setCustomValidity` https://jsfiddle.net/0bz3bkpz/. e.g. `checkboxGroup.each(function() {
       if (!isChecked) {
          this.setCustomValidity('Hello World');
       } else {
          this.setCustomValidity('');
       }
    });`

Answer (score 7):

i had the same problem, my solution was apply the required attribute to all elements

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkin_days[]" required="required" value="0" /><span class="w">S</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkin_days[]" required="required" value="1" /><span class="w">M</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkin_days[]" required="required" value="2" /><span class="w">T</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkin_days[]" required="required" value="3" /><span class="w">W</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkin_days[]" required="required" value="4" /><span class="w">T</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkin_days[]" required="required" value="5" /><span class="w">F</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkin_days[]" required="required" value="6" /><span class="w">S</span>
```

when the user check one of the elements i remove the required attribute from all elements:

```
var $checkedCheckboxes = $('#recurrent_checkin :checkbox[name="checkin_days[]"]:checked'),
    $checkboxes = $('#recurrent_checkin :checkbox[name="checkin_days[]"]');

$checkboxes.click(function() {

if($checkedCheckboxes.length) {
        $checkboxes.removeAttr('required');
    } else {
        $checkboxes.attr('required', 'required');
    }

 });
```

Comment: The name shouldn't include brackets, but most importantly this is a bad solution because you're having contradicting semantics vs logic. The previous answer is the more correct way but if you want a jQuery polyfill version try this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535187/jquery-validate-form-with-multiple-checkboxes-at-least-one-must-be-checked

Answer (score 7):

Here is improvement for icova's answer. It also groups inputs by name.

```
$(function(){
  var allRequiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');
  var checkboxNames = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < allRequiredCheckboxes.length; ++i){
    var name = allRequiredCheckboxes[i].name;
    checkboxNames.push(name);
  }

  checkboxNames = checkboxNames.reduce(function(p, c) {
    if (p.indexOf(c) < 0) p.push(c);
    return p;
  }, []);

  for (var i in checkboxNames){
    !function(){
      var name = checkboxNames[i];
      var checkboxes = $('input[name="' + name + '"]');
      checkboxes.change(function(){
        if(checkboxes.is(':checked')) {
          checkboxes.removeAttr('required');
        } else {
          checkboxes.attr('required', 'required');
        }
      });
    }();
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my more than 5 hours. This solutions works for all usecases where more than one group of checkboxes are there.

Comment: Can guide how I can change message of error? As if i use onvalid this gets broken.

Answer (score 3):

A little jQuery fix:

```
$(function(){
    var chbxs = $(':checkbox[required]');
    var namedChbxs = {};
    chbxs.each(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        namedChbxs[name] = (namedChbxs[name] || $()).add(this);
    });
    chbxs.change(function(){
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var cbx = namedChbxs[name];
        if(cbx.filter(':checked').length>0){
            cbx.removeAttr('required');
        }else{
            cbx.attr('required','required');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on icova's answer, here's the code so you can use a custom HTML5 validation message:

```
$(function() {
    var requiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');
    requiredCheckboxes.change(function() {
        if (requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');}
        else {requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');}
    });
    $("input").each(function() {
        $(this).on('invalid', function(e) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity('');
            if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
                e.target.setCustomValidity('Please, select at least one of these options');
            }
        }).on('input, click', function(e) {e.target.setCustomValidity('');});
    });
});
```

Comment: Anyway to get this worked if multiple set of checkboxes are there on same page?

Answer (score 0):

```
var verifyPaymentType = function () {
   //coloque os checkbox dentro de uma div com a class checkbox
  var inputs =  window.jQuery('.checkbox').find('input');
  var first = inputs.first()[0];

  inputs.on('change', function () {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  });

  first.setCustomValidity( window.jQuery('.checkbox').find('input:checked').length === 0 ? 'Choose one' : '');
}

window.jQuery('#submit').click(verifyPaymentType);

}
```